# Thread.sleep() skips to last method in Java/Android

Tags: android, multithreading, sleep

While there must be a better tactic of completing a countdown I have set up in my application, it seemed clear to me that using `Thread.sleep(1000)` between every digit would work. It did not and I still do not have any other solution. When I run the app, the countdown goes from 5, straight to 1 in 1 second.

This is my code:

```
bBegin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           bBegin.setText("5");

            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch(InterruptedException ie){

            }


            bBegin.setText("4");

            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch(InterruptedException ie){

            }

            bBegin.setText("3");

            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch(InterruptedException ie){

            }

            bBegin.setText("2");

            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch(InterruptedException ie){

            }

            bBegin.setText("1");

            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch(InterruptedException ie){

            }
}
```

Thanks, I hope this problems helps other noobs like me (and no worries, I did check the site for a previous solution)

Answer (score 3):

`Thread.sleep(1000);`   Bad! You are calling `sleep()` on the `UI thread` which you alsmost, if ever, never want to do. The `UI` will sleep for that amount of time. Use `CountDownTimer` instead.

[CountDownTimer Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

There are certainly other ways but this one should be good to accomplish what you want.

**Example**

In your case you might use a `CountDownTimer` something like this.

Create an inner class

```
private class MyCountDown extends CountDownTimer
{
    long duration, interval;
    public MyCountDown(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) 
   {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        duration = millisInFuture;
        interval = countDownInterval;
        int secs = 5;  // varaible for counter to be placed in TextView
        start();
    }

           @Override
    public void onTick(long duration) 
   {
        bBegin.setText(String.valueOf(secs));           
        secs = secs - 1;            
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        secs = 5; // reset counter if needed or do anything else you need when countdown is over
    }
```

And call it in `onClick()` like

```
MyCountDown timer = new MyCountDown(5000, 1000);  // local variable but might want to make it a member variable
```

Answer (score 2):

Sleep doesn't "skip" anything - instead, this code *prevents the UI from updating* until after the method ends (after it sleeps all 5 times).

At some point *after* the onClick method ends - and the UI dispatch can resume operation - the UI is updated. When this update occurs the display is updated with the last value assigned, which leads to the incorrect conclusion that code was "skipped". However, *all of the code in the method ran*.

This leads us to a very important rule: **do not sleep on the main-UI thread**. Doing so *blocks* user interaction and it *blocks* display updates because it *blocks* the UI event/dispatch queue. All standard UI callbacks, such as click listeners, occur *on* the UI thread.

Where sleep *is* required - as in the case of games and custom canvases, say - the sleep is done on a different (non UI) thread so that it does not cause such primary UI blocking behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
**As in the attached code snippet it is showing user thread is trying to update UI Thread.which is not a good practice..
i have done same using the concept of Handler.
the code snipper is ..**


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView tv;
    Button b1;
    Handler handler;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        handler= new Handler();


        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Runnable r=new Runnable() {
                    int   mynumber=5;
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        while(mynumber >0){
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    tv.setText("remaining time  is "+mynumber );
                                }
                            });

                            mynumber--;
                        }
                    }
                };

                new Thread(r).start();
            }
        });


    }

}
```